# drupal_add_js cannot find my javascript file

Tags: 7, javascript

I am trying to add a simple footer.js to my page.  I created a new block and put it in the footer.  I then use PHP snippet in the body of the block with the PHP code:

```
<?php
drupal_add_js('footer.js');
?>
```

When viewing the source code, footer.js is there but when I click on it, it is a 404 error (not found).  The footer.js is located under: /var/www/drupal/sites/www.example.com/footer.js. Then I tried:

```
<?php
drupal_add_js('footer.js', array('type' => 'file', 'scope' => 'footer'));
?>
```

I don't think that is working, either.  I think the issue is with the path.  Any ideas, or do I have to write a custom module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely a path issue, you should be able to use the [`DRUPAL_ROOT`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/install.php/constant/DRUPAL_ROOT/7) constant to get the correct one:

```
$path = DRUPAL_ROOT . '/sites/www.example.com/footer.js';
drupal_add_js($path);
```

Comment: Great! Now when I click on the footer.js via the source code of the web page, it opens up the javascript file. Now, is the javascript file the standard type (i.e. <script type="text/javascript"></script>), or is it that weird jQuery format that Drupal wants for inline (i.e. (function ($) {... })(jQuery);)

Comment: It's the second one, that wraps your javascript so it's nice and jQuery context-safe

Comment: Is there any way to bypass this jQuery format and use pure and strict javascript syntax?  jQuery makes no sense to me, and my code I want to embed is in javascript.  In Drupal 6, it was simple to just copy/paste javascript code directly into the footer and voila - it worked!  Looks like they took this out in Drupal 7

Comment: If its just normal js just put that directly in the external file (no script tags) and it will work. Do me a favour and up vote the answer, some idiot down voted it even though it's correct! There's a lot of unfulfilled people out there with nothing better to do!

Comment: I was able to get it to work by finding a module.  What I wanted to do was embed a Piwik javascript code in the footer of my webpage.  Apparently the process to embed javascript is so complicated that Piwik has a Drupal 7 module for it, BUT, I did learn from their module that you can put 'inline' javascript code.  That is good to know.  Anyhow, thank you for your quick response and suggestions.  You did ultimately answer my question of finding the javascript file, although I could not get the javascript to work.  Thanks!